# Create View with cumulative counts for a fixed set of value-range

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to create BQ View on this table:

> mytable
>   id | value
>   s1 | 21
>   s2 | 31
>   s3 | 71

the View need to  count each of the above row(id), in each of the 10 fixed milestones when  value <= milestoneValue

Resulting view with 10 milestone rows for mytable will be:

> milestoneValue | count
>   100 | 3
>   90  | 3 (all s1 s2 s3)
>   80  | 3
>   70  | 2 (s1,s2)
>   60..
>   30  | 1
>   20  | 1
>   10  | 1

I did not find any suitable  function to compute this. I could add the 10 binary flag as columns on the raw data in mytable, that I could SUM, but do not see a way to transform that to a 10 row milestone View.
I tried:

```
SELECT  id, value,   
IF(value <= 10 , 1, 0) as M10,   
IF(value <= 20 , 1, 0) as M20,    
 ...   
IF(value <= 90 , 1, 0) as M90,   
IF(value <= 100 , 1, 0) as M100    
FROM mytable ;
```

Help appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT bucket, SUM(word_count>bucket)
FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare] a
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT bucket FROM (SELECT 10 bucket), (SELECT 20 bucket), (SELECT 30 bucket), (SELECT 40 bucket)
) b
GROUP BY bucket
```

[image: results]